# Alt Coin Market Caps

Tags: pine-script

I see that it is possible to view the market cap of several Alt Coins, as detailed within https://uk.tradingview.com/markets/cryptocurrencies/global-charts/

But is it possible to view the coins market cap within the "Others" element. So for example how would I view the market cap of ALGO or VET or ATOM on Trading View.

I noticed that the below script can display the market cap for NEO so it must be possible.
https://uk.tradingview.com/script/0Wxbk0SU-NEO-Market-Cap/

Comment: Not possible. There is no available datafeed on tradingview with the crypto's issued supply. The GrantPeace's script is a total bs, just a hardcoded 'close*65000000'. You can spend 5 minutes to decompile the script and verify it by yourself.

Comment: Thank you for your reply @jonsharpe.
Do you know it there is a way to pull external data in from a feed to achieve the above?

Comment: Nope, unfortunately there is no way to feed the external data in pinescript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for the above replies.

I thought I would update and close this question incase someone in the future looks into it, hopefully this will save them time.

I did some further research and you can use the below code to extract Market Cap for Alts down to IOTA

IOTA_TICKER_POINTER = "CRYPTOCAP:" + "IOTA"
as per https://uk.tradingview.com/markets/cryptocurrencies/global-charts/ (Total Market Capitalization Dominance, % - chart)

But as can be seen in the above chart, there is an "Others" element that captures all the smaller Market Caps.

I was trying to extract the info from the "Others" element, but I found that this was not possible.

The only way was to manually configure the "Price X Circulating Supply".